# In Oracle SQL, how to join tables with multi-valued column

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a legacy table in our Oracle database which has a column that takes comma-separated values. These comma-separated values are actually foreign keys to another table.

```
Table: SCHEDULE
-----------------------
ID    NAME     DATES
--    ----     -----
1     Test1    10,20,30
2     Test2    20,40

Table: DATES
-----------------------
ID    DATE
--    ----
10    2013-01-01
20    2013-02-02
30    2013-03-03
40    2013-04-04
```

I'm trying to write a query that would return something like below result:

```
ID   NAME   DATE
--   ----   ----
1    Test1  2013-01-01
1    Test1  2013-02-02
1    Test1  2013-03-03
2    Test2  2013-02-02
2    Test2  2013-04-04
```

I came across DBMS_UTILITY.comma_to_table procedure, and functions like REGEXP_SUBSTR, SPLIT, JOIN, etc. But I'm not able to achieve this. Any help here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yuch.  But sometimes you have to deal with this.  In Oracle, you can use `like` for the `join` condition:

```
select s.id, s.name, d.date
from schedule s join
     dates d
     on ',' || dates || ',' like '%,' || d.id || ',%';
```

This is not efficient and it won't make use of indexes.  But it should solve your problem.

Note the use of the delimiter `','`.  This prevents `10` from matching `100`.

Comment: Awesome. It works if there is no space after comma. How to make it work regardless of space after comma?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. I added replace() function around dates column.

Answer (score 1):

Long term, the proper fix is to normalize the data by creating an intermediate many-to-many table. If you still need to maintain the DATES CSV column for legacy code, you could still maintain it with a trigger. But that is easy enough and I won't include that below. Here is a simple script to normalize the data and generate the relationship table from existing data.

```
create table schedule_dates
(
 schedule_id int,
 date_id int,
 primary key(schedule_id, date_id)
);
```

Populate the linking table (many to many)

```
insert into schedule_dates
  select a.id, b.id from schedule a join dates b
                         on ','||a.dates||',' like '%,'||b.id||'%,';
```

Create a view to hide the linking table:

```
create view V$SCHEDULE as
 select a.id, a.name, c.ts
    from schedule a
      join schedule_dates b on a.id = b.schedule_id
        join dates c on b.date_id = c.id
;
```

Query the view:

```
select * from V$SCHEDULE;

        ID NAME                 TS
---------- -------------------- ------------------
         1 Test1                12-APR-14
         1 Test1                12-MAY-14
         1 Test1                11-JUN-14
         2 Test2                12-MAY-14
         2 Test2                11-JUL-14
```

Comment: The `V$` prefix is usually used by Oracle only. I would avoid naming views (or anything else) using that - although it won't probably create any problems it will confuse people because most will assume that `V$SCHEDULE` is an Oracle (internal) view - or they might actually introduce one like that.

Comment: Normal schema users wont usually have DBA or catalog privileges on SYS.V$ views, plus a local view with that name wouldnt be a problem. But your point is well taken. That said, I've been doing it for 18 years without a problem, but I guess I also know which names to avoid. I like the V$ naming convention, but adjust it to taste.